# Как правильно сверстать flexbox?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Никак не получается выровнять `.logo` по центру, при этом чтобы два элемента меню `.right-items` прижимались к правому краю

```css
menu {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

menu .items {
  margin: 0 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

menu .items.left {
  text-align: right;
}

menu .items.right {}

menu .items a {
  margin: 0 12.5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

menu .items .right-items {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

menu .logo {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <div class="items left">
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo"></div>

  <div class="items right">
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
    <a href="">Пункт</a>

    <a href="" class="right-items">Пункт</a>
    <a href="" class="right-items">Пункт</a>
  </div>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если задача стоит именно на flex то вот, можно конечно еще чистить код но ваша задача решена. Вкратце обернуть пункты в свои дивы и растянуть.

```css
a {
  margin: 0 12.5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

menu .items {
  margin: 0 20px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.left {
  text-align: right;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

menu .logo {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <div class="items left">
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
    <a href="">Пункт</a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo"></div>

  <div class="items right">

    <div class="">
      <a href="">Пункт</a>
      <a href="">Пункт</a>
      <a href="">Пункт</a>
    </div>

    <div class="">
      <a href="" class="right-items">Пункт</a>
      <a href="" class="right-items">Пункт</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</menu>
```

Comment: А без обертки? Или есть другое решение чтоб при этом не возится потом в вертикальным выравниванием пунктов. Можно как-то сделать чтобы right и left занимали по половине независимо от контента внутри?

Comment: Ну вообще то есть же еще абсолютное и относительное позиционирование, но тогда будут заморочки в адаптивностью.